# Cordova Android App Use deafult Media Player

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap

How can I use deafault media player (VLC, MX player) to play remote videos in my corodova / phonegap / ionic android app.

Any ideas will be very helpful.
Thanks

Comment: use webintent plugin to launch your video : https://github.com/cordova-misc/cordova-webintent

Comment: That was exactly what I needed, works great.